# Spring security cannot logout

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, logout, spring-session

I've my custom implementation of Spring security in a Spring boot application. So I have my dependencies and I've a class named SecurityImpl which implements for me the login access.
When I get on the browser I'm correctly asked to login with an alert. When I login I have access to all of the @RequestMapping of my Spring Controller correctly. But I remain always logged. Even if I delete the JSESSIONID from my browser, when I make another http request, I am allowed and a new JSESSIONID is created and sent to my browser.

One weird thing is that even when I access with the login for the first time, even when the cookie is authomatically generated, the expiration date is: 1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z

I've tried to invalidate the session, to delete the cookies from the server, to logout in various ways but nothing. Once logged, I am always allowed.

Here my SecurityImpl.java class which configurates my Spring Security:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Configuration
@Component
public class SecurityImpl extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements AuthenticationProvider {

  public static final String ROLE_ADMIN = "ROLE_ADMIN";
  public static final String ROLE_USER = "ROLE_USER";

  @Autowired UtenteDao utenteDao;

  /* authentication provider part */

  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {

    String username = auth.getName();
    String password = auth.getCredentials().toString();
    String ruolo = "";

    Optional<Utente> utenteOptional = utenteDao.findByCodiceFiscaleAndPassword(username, password);

    if(utenteOptional.isPresent()){
        ruolo = utenteOptional.get().getRuolo();
    }
    if(ROLE_ADMIN.equals(ruolo)) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
        grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(ROLE_USER));
        grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(ROLE_ADMIN));
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, grantedAuths);
    } else if(ROLE_USER.equals(ruolo)){
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
        grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(ROLE_USER));
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, grantedAuths);
    } else {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Autenticazione fallita");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> auth) {
    return auth.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
  }



  /* websecurity adapter part: erase it if you don't want login alert but default spring login web page */

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(this); //this because it is either a WebSecurityAdapter than an AuthenticationProvider
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .logout().clearAuthentication(true).logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/test")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true);
  }

  /*  per non filtrare con il login alcuni path  */
  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/test");
  }

}
```

It doesn't work: when I go to /logout I'm redirected to /test correctly but when I ask for a forbidden path I'm allowed without any login.

Then I tried some solution in my @RestController:

```
@RequestMapping("/logout")
public String logoutPage (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token) {
    token.eraseCredentials();
    token.setAuthenticated(false);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
    return "<h1>Logout effettuato con successo.</h1>";
}
```

then I tried:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logout")
public String loadApp(HttpServletRequest request) {
    HttpSession session= request.getSession(false);
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    if(session != null) {
        session.invalidate();
    }
    return "<h1>Logout effettuato con successo.</h1>";
}
```

Then, as a desperate, I tried:

```
@RequestMapping("/logout")
public String logoutDo(HttpServletRequest request){
    HttpSession session= request.getSession(false);
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    session= request.getSession(false);
    if(session != null) {
        session.invalidate();
    }
    for(Cookie cookie : request.getCookies()) {
        cookie.setMaxAge(0);
    }
    return "<h1>Logout effettuato con successo.</h1>";
}
```

I tried to use these methods and contemporarily delete my cookie from the browser. I've also tried to preauthorize forbidden method with the annotation @PreAuthorize, in the case they would be allowed (when you open a new browser, before first login, they are NOT allowed even without @PreAuthorize, but when login is made, IS FOREVER!)

Comment: you have to remove or need to expire token from token store when logout api is hit.

Comment: Do you mean in the browser? I already do that and you know something? It's recreated with this expiration data: 1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z

Comment: You are using basic authentication... Basic authentication and logout won't work. The browser, after authentication, will always send an authentication header. So basically you logout and with each request you will login again.

Comment: What to modify in order not to use basic authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the absence of the usage of showForm(). Without it, yes I insert my credentials within a Javascript alert which is presented to me. But no logout is possible.

So the code changes this way:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .logout().clearAuthentication(true).logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")) 
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/test") 
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true);


}
```